# Cannot get hash passed as reference in a module

Tags: perl, hash

I want to pass a hash reference to a module. But, in the module, I am not able to get the hash back.

The example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#code.pl
use strict;
use Module1;

my $obj = new Module1;

my %h = (
    k1 => 'V1'
);

print "reference on the caller", \%h, "\n";

my $y = $obj->printhash(\%h);
```

Now, Module1.pm:

```
package Module1;
use strict;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw();
use Data::Dumper;

sub new {
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $objref = {};
    bless $objref, $class;
    return $objref;
}


sub printhash {
    my $h = shift;

    print "reference on module -> $h \n";
    print "h on module -> ", Dumper $h, "\n";
}
1;
```

The output will be something like:

```
reference on the callerHASH(0x2df8528)
reference on module -> Module1=HASH(0x16a3f60)
h on module -> $VAR1 = bless( {}, 'Module1' );
$VAR2 = '
';
```

How can I get back the value passed by the caller?
This is an old version of perl: v5.8.3

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Exporter` for an object-oriented module. Just remove `use Exporter` and `our @EXPORT_OK`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Module1, change sub printhash to:

```
sub printhash {
    my ($self, $h) = @_;
    # leave the rest
}
```

When you invoke a method on a object as `$obj->method( $param1 )` the 
method gets the object itself as the first parameter, and $param1 as the second parameter.

[perldoc perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) - Object-Oriented Programming in Perl Tutorial

[perldoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) - Perl Object Reference

Answer (score 6):

When you call a sub as a method, the first value in `@_` will be the object you called it on.

The first argument you pass to it will be the **second** value in `@_`, which you are currently ignoring.

```
sub printhash {
    my ($self, $h) = @_;
```